# Setting curl switches in an http request on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, curl

I want to send an HTTP request, equivalent to the following `curl` command:

```
curl --data "..." -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

Here is how I've managed to get most of it in NodeJS:

```
let http = require("http");

let data = "...";

let options = {
    protocol: "http:",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8545,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

let req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    ...
});

req.on("error", function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

How can I add the `-H` and `-X` switches which appear on the `curl` command?

The description for `curl` switches can be found [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

The description for `http.request` of can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

But I have not been able to conclude how to simply add those two switches into my HTTP request.

Comment: you already did ...

Answer (score 0):

-X and -H are not switches (like in on/off), they are parameters that require an extra argument to follow after them.

`-X <command>` refers to the request method, which you've already set as `method: "POST"` in your options object.

`-H <header>` refers to the request headers, which you've already set to `"Content-Type": "application/json"`

There is nothing else for you to do except sit back and relax while the program runs.